# Play RTSP streaming on android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I have a RTSP source, and I wanna play it on my android app, but it play on 2 or 3 minute and can't play longer :(

How can i play it longer?

```
// there is my code to play, thanks for advice!
// videoview is my VideoView on layout
    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.119/Bolt.ts"));   
    videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));    
    videoview.requestFocus();   
    videoview.start();
```

Thank for any help!

Comment: Show us the code or you're not going to get any help.

Comment: What happens after 2-3 minutes? Have you tried playing different videos?

Comment: No, after 2-3 minutes, it stop, and can't play continue

Comment: Any error messages in LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your video´s encoding is not fully supported, I suggest use the native player is a another good solution 
for playing RTSP.

```
mediaURL = "rtsp://192.168.0.119/Bolt.ts"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mediaURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Update:**

Ok, if you don´t want another app to play, your solution is correct

```
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.119/Bolt.ts"));   
videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));    
videoview.requestFocus();   
videoview.start();
```

But i´m pretty sure the reason that cause your video stops are the codecs used in the stream that probably are not fully  supported on your device.

I suggest to use: `H.264 for video` and `AAC for audio`.

Comment: I don't want to use another app to play

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the standard Android MediaPlayer does not send back a keep-alive message to the RTSP streaming server. Therefore, the streaming server terminates the connection.

A workaround is to use a different type of MediaPlayer:
- ExoPlayer (from Google)
- Vitamino (beware of licensing issues, which are not very clear)
- LibVlc

Personally, i used LibVlc, and it works well. You can find some examples here:
https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample

Comment: ExoPlayer _still_ does not yet support RTSP. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/55